# R package installed in 2 different locations

Tags: r, package, installation, version

I have R package `ape` installed in 2 locations, that are BOTH part of the `.libPath()`
- `ape` version 3.3 in location1
- `ape` version 3.4 in location2

in `ape` version 3.4, there is a new function `clustalomega`. I have NOT loaded any of the 2 packages (using `library`)

`ape::clustalomega` doesn't work on my machine. I suspect it comes from the fact that R is considering first the old version of `ape` it has found in location1.

I have tried to reverse the order of the libPath, with `.libPath(rev(.libPath())` but it didn't change anything.

Is there a way to ensure we take the package in priority from location 2 (I have no control on what is installed on location1)

Answer (score 1):

The solution lies with function `unloadNamespace`. It seems that when R is starting, eventhough it is not loading the `library("ape")`, it still loads the namespace of the package, from the first lib.loc it can find (in this case, location1)

So in order to force the loading of the namespace from another location, we need to do:

> ape::clustalomega # doesn't exist
>   'ape' %in% loadedNamespaces() #returns TRUE
>    unloadNamespace(ns = 'ape') 'ape' %in% loadedNamespaces() #returns FALSE 
>   loadNamespace(package = 'ape', lib.loc = location2)
>
> ape::clustalomega # now works